# The problem of get surface by rotating function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Got a question from an online course, I got the answer, but I had no idea why? I know the rotation to get the surface is to use intergral of $2 \pi r$, but it's so hard to understand why $r$ is like that?

Set up (but do not solve) the integral for the surface area of the surface
obtained by rotating the curve given by

$$x = acos^3(t), y = asin^3(t), 0 \leq t \leq π/2$$

about the x-axis. Here $a$ is an arbitrary constant

[answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvVtG.png)

I draw a picture of that curve
[mydrawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt1lH.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Welcome!
Please have a deep look at [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Area_of_Surface_of_Revolution_from_Astroid)

Comment: @Mikasa Thanks! Looks like my understanding of the equation got wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the background to do the problems from the online course of course it will seem extremely difficult to understand, so perhaps downloading random problems and trying to puzzle them out isn't the best way to learn.

In the question the $x$ and the $y$ coordinates describe the line in terms of a parameter called $t$ which varies from 0 to $\pi/2$. The graph should look like this:

[image]

(from [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+x%3Dcos%5E3%28t%29%2C+y%3Dsin%5E3%28t%29%2C+t%3D0+to+pi%2F2))

Then you've got to integrate to get the surface area by rotating around the $x$ axis, which means the $y$ value multiplied by $2\pi$ multiplied by the slope of the curve. The slope of the curve is the part in the square root in that answer you've posted an image of.